# WebExtension does not start content script on Android (geckoview)

Tags: javascript, android, firefox-addon-webextensions

In a geckoview based app I need to display various errors in the browser window. Some of the buttons offered there have to be evaluated and processed further in the app.

I have tried various scenarios and have come to the conclusion that in order to be able to transfer information from the web page script to the app, I need to build a web extension with content script and background script.

That's why I wrote a WebExtension in which a web page script evaluates the click on the web button and forwards this information to the content script via `window.postMessage()`, which then forwards the information to the background script via `sendMessage()` (and this can send the data to the app via `sendNativeMessage()`).

My Extension works fine on a Firefox on PC where I can see the messages. But when I install it in my Android app (based on geckoview), the content_script does not start.

My manifest contains (amongst others) this:

```
“content_scripts”: [
  {
    “matches”: [“file:///*” , “<all_urls>”],
    “js”: [“content.js”]
  }
],
“permissions”: [
  “nativeMessaging”,
  “activeTab”,
  “storage”,
  “webRequest”,
  “<all_urls>”
]
```

The content script starts with the borderfy example to see whether the context script is executed or not:

```
  document.body.style.border = “5px solid red”;
  console.info(“Content Script!”);
```

When I load a normal web page (e.g. https://mozilla.com), the script is started (I see the red boarders).

Originally, I started the HTML file from resource but acording to “https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns” a pattern “resource://path/” is invalid. (The HTML page is currently not part of the webExtension.)

That’s why I added “file:///*” for content_script matches to the manifest and copied the HTML file to the local cache (and later to the download folder for testing) - but always the same: the content script does not start.

Comment: all_urls already includes file:// so the problem might be that GeckoView doesn't support this protocol.